# Manage Titles when Uploading Multiple Images

Tags: uploading, fine-uploader

It would be great if we could manage the titles of each image that we upload when uploading multiple images. This way I could select each image that I want to upload, title them, then hit the upload button. Right now one must either upload one by one or have all the selected images have the same title.

Kinda like Facebook or Panoramio where it's easy to manage the titles of the images before uploading.

Comment: Can you open up a feature request in the [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues) so we can discuss this a bit more in detail?  Stackoverflow exists to handle support requests only.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't natively supported in Fine Uploader at the moment, but I've opened up [a feature request](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/773) and tentatively scheduled it for the 3.7 milestone.  In the meantime, you can certainly provide your own UI elements to allow users to provide alternate names for each upload-able item and pass these new names as a parameter.  Server-side, you would have to parse this parameter and associate it with the uploaded item.  Fine Uploader will have to adopt a parameter name that contains the user-supplied alternate filename anyway (and the server will have to be aware of this convention and parse this parameter), since we won't be able to change the value file input field sent along with the multipart encoded request.

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I take it this doesn't affect the image title? I started this in hopes to make multiple titles manageable when uploading, kinda like Facebook when uploading pictures. The user is able to add titles to each pic rather than doing it one by one. I am trying to get this implemented into Joomgallery as seen here:
http://www.forum.en.joomgallery.net/index.php?topic=6196.msg19939#msg19939

Comment: How is joom determining the image title currently, in the context of fine uploader?  Also, 3.7 has not yet released.  In fact, I'm still working out a few UI bugs in the edit file name feature.

Comment: See the following message for an explanation on how the image title is used in the context of fine uploader:
http://www.forum.en.joomgallery.net/index.php?topic=6196.msg19958#msg19958

Joomgallery needs to be able to work with software licensed under GNU GPL v3 considering that it's free software in itself. What's the status on this?

Comment: We can continue this discussion in the forum post you have linked to.  I will follow up Sunday or Monday.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
var uploader = $('.uploader'),
    titleBox = $('input[type=text]');
uploader.fineUploader({
    request: {
         endpoint: 'path/to/url'
    },
    formatFileName: function (name) {
         var title = titleBox.val() + ' - ' + name + '';
         titleBox.val('');
         return title;
    },
});
uploader.on('submit', function (event, id, name) {
    uploader.fineUploader('setParams', {title: titleBox.val()}, id);
});
```

Comment: This assumes only one file will be uploaded, and, quite frankly, this will never work as is.  This type of behavior only makes sense with the autoUpload option set to false, and you will need to dynamically associate an input with each submitted file.